# What is the best way for a UK citizen to get a Chinese business visa while in America?

Tags: visas, china, uk-citizens, applications, working-visas

What is the best way for a UK citizen to get a Chinese business visa while in America? Can this be done and where do I have to go?

Comment: Did you check the website of the Chinese embassy in the USA? They will tell you the procedures

Comment: Please clarify whether you are resident in the USA or just there temporarily.

Comment: Also, we are assuming that by “America” you actually mean the USA. Please clarify if it isn’t the case.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.